# Problem with render users name and surnames on click in asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous

I've got a little problem, because I don't know how to render users after choosing them. I mean there are 3 lists: names, surnames and ids. I want to be able to print on screen in span their names and surnames after every change (after clicking). Unfortunately, I'm making that in vanilla js that's why it isn't as easy as in React :/

```js
let choices = {
    name: '',
    surname: '',
}
async function getData() {
    const url = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cuSKqtKmgi?indent=2';
    try {
        const res = await fetch(url);
        return await res.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
async function render() {


    const data = await getData()
    const nameList = document.querySelector('.name-list')
    const surnameList = document.querySelector('.surname-list')
    const idList = document.querySelector('.id-list')
    const div = document.querySelector('div');

    data.person.forEach((person) => {
        nameList.innerHTML += `<li class="name">${person.name}</li>`;
        surnameList.innerHTML += `<li class="surname">${person.surrname}</li>`;
        idList.innerHTML += `<li>${person.id}</li>`;
        div.innerHTML = "<span></span>"
    });

}
const getUser = () => {
    const names = document.querySelectorAll('.name')
    const surnames = document.querySelectorAll('.surname')
    const div = document.querySelector('div');
    names.forEach(name => {
        name.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            choices.name = e.target.textContent
            console.log(choices);

        })
    });
    surnames.forEach(surname => {
        surname.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            choices.surname = e.target.textContent
            console.log(choices);
        })
    });
    div.innerHTML = `User: <span>${choices.name}${choices.surname}</span>`
}

render().then(r => {
    getUser()

});
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav{ display: flex; justify-content: space-around; }
div{
    text-align: center;
}
.name, .surname{
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<nav>
        <ul class="name-list"></ul>
        <ul class="surname-list"></ul>
        <ul class="id-list"></ul>
    </nav>
    <div></div>
```

If something is unclear feel free to ask :)

Comment: If you want to model what React does, then I would suggest having a single `state` variable that holds the data from `getData` and `choices`. You call `render` with that `state` variable as an argument. In your event listeners, you update the `state` and pass it to `render`, which updates the screen accordingly.

Comment: @HereticMonkey this is a solution that I need, could you please insert this into the code and I'll surely give you the best solution for my problem :)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the following code inside each `addEventListener()` so that `div.innerHTML` will be updated every time after clicking.

```
div.innerHTML = `User: <span>${choices.name}${choices.surname}</span>`
```